# upload scanned book to OpenLibrary preserving metadata

Tags: scripting, command-line-interface, metadata

I have a lot of scanned books as a collection of jpeg images with their metadata:

- title
- author
- publisher
- date
- table of content
- ID
- scan info of each page

I wish to donate them to openlibrary.org including all the possible metadata.

Here (https://internetarchive.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli.html#upload) it is documented only how to upload books with some metadata.

How do I proceed to keep all the metadata including table of content with the InternetArchive cli (specifically table of content)?

Answer (score 0):

I use this cli regularly but what do you mean by "including table of contents"? If you are looking to mark a page as a "contents," it may be possible by including a scandata.xml with your upload, but I haven't tested this. See this [discussion on explicitly identifying a title page](https://archive.org/post/1010270/pdf-not-starting-on-page-1).